# How to prove that Tree $T_1$ has a perfect elimination scheme (PES)

Tags: complex-analysis, graph-theory

Give a tree graph  $T_1$ =$(V,E)$ how can we prove that it has a **P**erfect **E**limination **S**cheme   **:P.E.S**

**P.E.S** : is an ordering of the vertices, in such away that a vertex $v_i$ is simplical in the induced graph **G** on all vertices.

Comment: Find a leaf.  Remove it.  Repeat.

Comment: Does every node in a Tree build a clique ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $ T = (V,E) $ is a finite tree, it has exactly $ \left|V\right|-1 $ edges.  It's easy to show that if $ \left|V\right|>1 $ then there exists a vertex with degree 1 (otherwise there would be too many edges, or the tree wouldn't be connected).  Such a vertex is called a leaf.  If we remove a leaf, the resulting graph is still a tree, since we are neither disconnecting our tree nor creating a cycle.

Thus, we can keep removing these leaf vertices, getting back a tree each time, until we're left with one vertex.  Since a leaf has degree 1, it is trivially a clique with its neighbours.